# add directory to sudo path on wubi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sudo, wubi

I'm using wubi ubuntu which doesn't have a root account. I have php in a nonstandard location because of lamp. I would like to add a path to the sudo account so I can do sudo php -m for example.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
sudo su --c "php -m"
```

Answer (score 0):

Will it work if you add it to `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

What does your `/etc/sudoers` file look like?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work - i think that's only for regular users.